# Bug no arquivo do CSS externo

Tags: html5, css3, menu

Olá estou fazendo um menu full screen tipo hambúrguer para um site com CSS e HTML puro. Fiz o código desse menu separado. Mas o problema é que o codigo do CSS só funciona corretamente no estilo interno, quando eu copio o mesmo codigo para um arquivo css externo ele funciona de maneira errada. E o mais estranho, é que se eu copiar as 3 ultimas formatações do CSS e colar no estilo interno, funciona corretamente.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Menu</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="h-estilo.css">
    

</head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="menu-ham" autocomplete="off">
    <label for="menu-ham">
        <div class="menu">
            <span class="hamburguer"></span>
        </div>
    </label>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a> </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
*, *::after, *::before{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body{
    background: #81ecec;
}

.menu{
    background: #fff;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 25px;
    right: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px #fff,
                0 0 0 0px #fff;
    transition: box-shadow 1s ease-in-out;
}

.menu:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 8px #fff,
                0 0 0 8px #fff;
}

.hamburguer{
    display: block;
    background: black;
    width: 30px;
    height: 2px;
    position: relative;
    top: 28px;
    left: 15px;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburguer::before,
.hamburguer::after{
    content:'';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburguer::before{
    top: -10px;
}

.hamburguer::after{
    bottom: -10px;
}

input{
    display: none;
}

input:checked ~ label .menu{
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 130vw #fff, 
                0 0 0 130vh #fff;
}

input:checked ~ label .hamburguer{
        transform: rotate(45deg);

}
input:checked ~ label .hamburguer:before{
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    top: 0;
}

input:checked ~ label .hamburguer:after{
        transform: rotate(90deg);
        bottom: 0;  
}


ul{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    list-style: none; 
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
}

input:checked ~ ul{
        opacity: 1;
}

a{
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    color: #00cec9;
    font-size: 47px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Isso pode estar acontecendo devido a ordem que esse CSS foi colocado dentro do seu documento, ou simplesmente pq vc aplicou o estilo de forma "universal", direcionado diretamente para as tags como `a { }` ou `ul { }` dessa forma vc aplica o estilo em todos os Links da sua página, ou em todas as Lista!

Comment: Poderia ser isso se eu estivesse colocado mais `ul { }` e links `a{ }`. Mas só  tem essa `ul { }` e são só esses links `a{ }` que que tem no código. Até tentei aqui fazer do jeito que falou, colocando um seleção exclusiva pra essas tags, mas o erro permanece.